# Make autonumbering python (tab delimited file)

Tags: python, numbers

I would like to make an automatic numbering 2,4 or 8 fold by giving 3 parameters: maximum number of records, maximum number of columns, and a start number.

So 3 variable data that I call later and then write a tab delimited file.

I don't know how to do that.

```
# startnumber is 100% variable
quantity = 1000
# Column can be 2,4 or 8
column = 2
# startnumber is 100% variable
startnumber = 500

# I need 500,501,...,999 (Don't know how to syntax this)
lst1 = list(startnumber + 1, (quantity / column)times)

# I need 1000,1001,...1499 (Don't know how to syntax this)
lst2 = list((startnumber + (quantity / column)) + 1, (quantity / column)times)

with open('DATA.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(("NR1") + "\t" + ("NR2") + "\n")
    for row in zip(lst1, lst2):
        row_str = "\t".join(str(x).zfill(4) for x in row)
        f.write(row_str + "\n")
```

Comment: Why not generate your list as you write the file? That would reduce the amount of data you need. Anyway you need to use list(range()) to generate you lists.

Comment: This was the start of the original  script. But then I need to manual give start en end.
lst1 = list(range(8001,8500+1))
lst2 = list(range(8501,9000+1))

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the relational operator in the 4th case of the loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).